# Customizing the height in bar chart matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart

How can I force one of the bars to touch the roof of the plot in the matplotlib bar chart? there always a gap between them

Comment: [`plt.ylim(0, max(my_data))`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html)?

Comment: It's correct. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using plt.ylim(top = max(...)) as below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

months = ["March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"]
cases = [1000, 2000, 5000, 8000, 15000, 6000]

plt.bar(months, cases, width=0.5, color="orange", label="All cases")
plt.ylim(top = max(cases))
plt.show()
```

[image]